# Prove if this sequence is converge or diverge and find its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Given the sequence $f(n):=1+\frac{n\cos(n \pi/2)}{n+1}$, find if it converges.

How can I use the inequality to prove this question. Moreover I don't know how to use the inequality which says $|f(n) -L|< \epsilon$

Comment: $$\text{Is that the sequence}\;\;1+\frac n{n+1}\cos\frac{n\pi}2\;?$$

Comment: yes it is the sequence

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The sequence 
$$f(n):=1+\frac{n\cos(n \pi/2)}{n+1}$$ 
has no limit. Try to find two subsequences which have different limits. 
Recall that for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$,
$$\cos(n\pi/2)=\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if $n$ is odd,}\\
1 &\text{if $n$ is divisible by $4$,}\\
-1 &\text{if $n-2$ is divisible by $4$.}\\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: how do i find that

Comment: Try $n = 2k + 1$ and $n = 2k$.

Comment: First of all, what are the values of $\cos(n\pi /2)$ when $n$ is an integer?

Comment: if n is 1 is 0 if n is 2 is -1

Comment: how will i know i will use 2k+1 or 2k

Comment: What are the values of $\cos(n\pi /2)$ for ANY  integer $n$?

Comment: cos( pi/2) = 0 cos(2pi/2)=-1

Comment: they are 0 and -1

Comment: Are you sure? See above.

Comment: Am using the sequence above

Comment: Now "guess" some subsequences which have limit.